# cudaMallocManaged() returns "operation not supported"

Tags: cuda

Trying out managed memory in CUDA 6.0 gives me `operation not supported` when calling `cudaMallocManaged()`.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"

#include <stdio.h>

#define CHECK(r) {_check((r), __LINE__);}

void _check(cudaError_t r, int line) {
  if (r != cudaSuccess) {
    printf("CUDA error on line %d: %s\n", line, cudaGetErrorString(r), line);
    exit(0);
  }
}

int main()
{
  int *c;
  CHECK(cudaMallocManaged(&c, sizeof(int)));
  *c = 0;
  return 0;
}
```

GeForce GTX 750 Ti (Maxwell), compiled with CUDA 6.0 using compute_50,sm_50. Windows 7 64-bit. Tested with drivers 335.23 (whql) and 337.50 (beta). Visual Studio 2012. Tried 32-bit debug and release builds.

> C:\rd\projects\cpp\test_cuda6\test_cuda6>"C:\Program
>   Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\bin\nvcc.exe"
>   -gencode=arch=compute_50,code=\"sm_50,compute_50\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2012 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin"  -I\C\common\inc -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include"     --keep-dir Release -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -cudart static     -DWIN32 -DNDEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3
>   /nologo /O2 /Zi  /MD  " -o Release\kernel.cu.obj
>   "C:\rd\projects\cpp\test_cuda6\test_cuda6\kernel.cu"

The program runs without error if I replace `cudaMallocManaged()` with `cudaMalloc()`.

Any ideas on how to get `cudaMallocManaged()` working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Tried 32-bit debug and release builds.

Use a 64 bit debug or release build.

From [the documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-requirements):

> J.1.4. System Requirements
>
> Unified Memory has three basic requirements:
>
> •a GPU with SM architecture 3.0 or higher (Kepler class or newer)
>
> •a 64-bit host application and operating system, except on Android
>
> •Linux or Windows

64 bit host application means you cannot compile for a 32 bit debug or release build.

Comment: Heh -- read through the system requirements and completely missed the 64-bit app requirement. This is the first time I've encountered anything where a 64-bit build is required. Do you know the technical reason? Thanks again for your help. It's much appreciated as always.

Comment: UM needs a unified address space across all GPUs in the system, and the CPU, [just like UVM/UA](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__UNIFIED.html#group__CUDART__UNIFIED).  This is simpler to accomplish in a 64-bit space.